# python: I need to understand better imports and packages

Tags: python, import, package

My application has a structure similar to this one:

```
myapp.py
basemod.py
[pkg1]
    __init__.py
    mod1.py
[pkg2]
    __init__.py
    mod2.py
```

`myapp.py`:

```
import pkg1
import pkg2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pkg1.main()
    pkg2.main()
```

`basemod.py`:

```
import pkg1


def get_msg():
    return pkg1.msg
```

`pkg1/__init__.py`:

```
import mod1

msg = None


def main():
    global msg
    mod1.set_bar()
    msg = mod1.bar
```

`pkg1/mod1.py`:

```
bar = None


def set_bar():
    global bar
    bar = 'Hello World'
```

`pkg2/__init__.py`:

```
import mod2


def main():
    mod2.print_foo()
```

`pkg2/mod2.py`:

```
import basemod

foo = basemod.get_msg()


def print_foo():
    print(foo)
```

If I run `myapp.py` I get:

```
None
```

While in my mind I'd expect:

```
Hello World
```

My goal is to keep the two packages completely independent from each other, and only communicating through `basemod.py`, which is a sort of API to `pkg1`.
I'm starting to think that I have not completely understood how imports among packages work, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: this sounds like a job for `import pdb`, `pdb.set_trace()`

Comment: module in python is in someways similar to a singleton.  after your line `pkg1.main()`, but before your line `pkg2.main()` you will have `pkg1.msg == pkg1.mod1.bar == 'Hello World'`, but still `pkg2.mod2.foo is None` (as was assigned at of import)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Took me a while to read through all that code, but it looks like your problem is in pkg2/mod2.py. The line `foo = basemod.get_msg()` is executed the first time that file is imported, and never again. So by the time you change the value of `mod1.bar`, this has already executed, and `foo` is `None`.

The solution should simply be to move that line into the `print_foo` function, so it is only executed when that function is called - which is after the code that sets the relevant value.

Comment: You are perfectly right, I was so convinced that it had to be a problem with imports that I was completely ignoring that line. Thank you so much!